# Style messed up in various wordpress plugins

Tags: css, wordpress

Actually this might just be a very general problem and not just affecting a few plugins. Still I'll name Nimble Portfolio and Awesome Filterable Portfolio because I noticed it with those first.

Nimble portfolio is supposed to create something like this:
[image: Nimble portfolio screenshot]

But in my WordPress website it looks like this:
[image: Broken Nimble portfolio screenshot]

It's not because of my theme because I've tried numerous other themes including the default ones.

Any clue what's going on??

A working example: [here](http://nimble3.com/portfolio) , and my site where it doesn't work: [here](http://ankit-arora.com/)

I've been clueless with this problem for so many days now.

Answer (score 1):

In your `http://ankit-arora.com/wp-content/themes/manifest_v1.1/style.css` change line 346 to:

```
#coreContent li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Or perhaps better add the css to class `bigcard`. I can't find it on your page anymore..there was a `template.css` file:

```
li.bigcard {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You should learn to work with chrome developer-tools or firebug. There you see the actual style the element gets and can edit it in browser for preview.

Comment: I do work with chrome dev tools, but I supposed that since it's a plugin, it should be handling it's own style and I shouldn't have to hack together the CSS to make it work. And I don't think it's just the list style which is causing the problem plus isn't it a bad idea to needlessly edit my entire theme's style to fix this issue?